# HTML file upload uploads missing icon instead of chosen image

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

So I am going to be making a *very, very, **very*** simple photo cloud storage using Firebase's Storage. Everything is going as planned except when I upload an image through HTML to send to the backend, it just sends something similar like this:
[image]

And that's the missing image icon! So here is my code for the file upload:

```html
<!--HTML code, inside of a public folder-->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/submit-form">
    <input name="file" type="file" accept="image/png" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

```js
//The code which sends the image to firebase's Storage
var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
app.post('/submit-form', (req, res) => {
    var imageChosen = `${req.body.file}`; //I know it's useless to add the `${}` but I just do it, ok!
    fs.writeFile('sentImage.png', imageChosen, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
    });
  bucket.upload('sentImage.png');
    res.end('Image sent!')
});
```

So why is it only sending the missing image icon?

## The point

If you don't want the detailed explanation, here is a summary below:

I am sending an image through an HTML form inside of a public folder, then it saves it to a local file and uploads it to Firebase's Storage, except that it's sending the missing image icon instead of the image uploaded through the HTML form.

## How the cloud storage works

So basically you upload an image, then HTML sends the file to the backend. After that the backend uses the `fs` module to save it to a local file for Firebase to upload it to it's Storage

Comment: `bucket.upload` now happens too early, should be placed befor `});`,